# EMAILS CLUSTERING

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have email data (first_name, last_name, email, username, email_domain), and I want to cluster email  based on its text so it could be cluster similar emails together, it could be cluster similar names together. What I am thinking to do is to apply text preprocessing on email_domain and train a KMeans algorithm. am I on the right way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *an* approach, but whether it's the best one depends on the problem.

Exactly how you do that text preprocessing will matter a lot more than what clustering algorithm you use. The mapping from the text to a vector space determines what it *means* for two emails to be similar. The clustering algorithm just groups the ones that are most similar. (As an aside, I would think that the email *text* would be a more useful field to cluster on than the domain.)
There are lots of options for mapping arbitrary text onto a single vector. A couple papers to get you started: [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf) (the θ vector will be the one you want), [Paragraph Vectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4053).

K-Means is a reasonable choice if you know how many clusters you want. When deciding what properties you want your clustering algorithm to have, the [scikit-learn page on clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) is a useful resource. It shows datasets with a variety of shapes, along with the clusters that are extracted from each by the various algorithms.